# Is it possible to add a user with login to readonly database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, geo-replication

I have a sql azure database which is geo-replicated. Now I want to create a user with login and grant him a permission to read data from some table in the readonly replica.
But it seems like it's not possible.

When I'm trying to create a user for login I get a error message about readonly database:

```
 CREATE USER [user_name] FOR LOGIN [login_name]
```

> Failed to update database "test-master" because the database is
>   read-only.

When I'm trying to make a database read-write it tells me that it's not possible because of geo-replication:

```
 ALTER DATABASE [test-master] SET READ_WRITE
```

> ODBC error: State: 42000: Error: 1468 Message:'[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL
>   Server][SQL Server]The operation cannot be performed on database
>   "test-master" because it is involved in a database mirroring session
>   or an availability group. Some operations are not allowed on a
>   database that is participating in a database mirroring session or in
>   an availability group.'. Msg 5069, Level 16, State 3, Line 5 ALTER
>   DATABASE statement failed.

So is it possible at all?

**UPDATE:**

It's seems like login info is not replicated.

Script User as CREATE TO in Master db:

```
CREATE USER [user_name] FOR LOGIN [login_name] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
```

Script User as CREATE TO in Replica db:

```
CREATE USER [user_name] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
```

Does it mean that it's not possible to add a new login to the replica db?

Comment: Have you tried creating the login at the server level and mapping that to the read-only db?

Comment: You should create the user in your primary database and then it will be available on replicas.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin Yes, I've already created a user in the primary DB and it's copied to replica automatically but it seems like I cannot login to replica under its credentials

Comment: That means you already have the user in your database and you don't have to create it. I can suppose that you created the logins for that user on your servers separately, that's why they have different SIDs.  Recreate the login on a replica with a correct SID from the primary server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2018/05/21/tips-tricks-what-you-need-to-do-to-creat-sql-login-to-authenticate-to-azure-sql-dbs-members-in-auto-failover-group/

It's possible to use `Forced Failover` feature which swap databases and hence make my replica writable so I can create a user and grant permissions(of course during this change previous master db becomes readonly).

Comment: @AlbertoMorillo SO allows me to do so only in 2 days